# Assigning object property as input parameter for function of another object

Tags: swift, function, class, properties

I'm trying to assign the property of one subclass object as an input parameter for the function of another subclass, but encountered an instance member issue:

```
import UIKit

class p1 {
    var quality1 = 0
    var quality2 = 0
}
class p11 : p1 {
    func interact(class: p12) {
        quality1 += p12.quality2 //error: Instance member 'quality2' cannot be used on type 'p12'
    }
}
class p12 : p1 {
    func interact(class: p11) {   
    }
}
var p11a = p11()
p11a.quality1 = 100
p11a.quality2 = 100
var p12a = p12()
p12a.quality1 = 120
p12a.quality2 = 80
```

How do I solve this so that one object's properties are affected by the properties of another object through a function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're missing something :) the method `interact` in `p11` class should be:

```
func interact(parameter: p12) {
    quality1 += parameter.quality2 // changing 'p12' to 'parameter' (instead of 'class')
}
```

You should call `quality2` property via the passed parameter, not via the class name itself.

Comment: Oops, my mistake! That worked out very well, thanks!